# angularjs login application using java spring MVC

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am a beginner trying to learn AngularJS and trying to work on a login application.
Can anyone please share any github url for login application using AngularJS and Java Spring MVC.
(Please dont mark this question as spam or duplicate. Those who wish to help alone could help)

Answer (score 1):

Here you have tons of good resources:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii

https://github.com/philipsorst/angular-rest-springsecurity

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angularjs/java-spring-security

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fx7hoza7wIA